# Mybb noCaptcha reCaptcha not working on server but working on localhost

Tags: php, cpanel, recaptcha, mybb

Recently I installed MyBB on my web server and for stop spam, I also configured Google noCaptcha reCaptcha.

The problem here was, When I tried to register on the forum, It says `An error occurred with the human verification. Please try again.`

Anyway I, I tried two three-time to register but Can't register the same problem comes again and again.

I installed the same MyBB script on my local server by using Xampp and there captcha working fine on it. I checked the privet key and public key well, Everything seems good.

I already ran Vanilla Forum on the same server and worked with noCaptcha reCaptcha. On Vanilla Forum its worked but on MyBB its not.

Please help me to get out from this problem.

My site address which causing the problem is : http://forum.howi.in

Comment: dude its working , I checked in member.php,..

Comment: I checked the member page too. No one registered yet. Because no one can't because of the NoCaptcha reCaptcha Human verification problem. I hope you ticked the negative.

Comment: The user that you found on the member list was me and its administrator. Not a normal user who registered normally.

Comment: Make the post positive. Without checking the problem carefully. You made the post to negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issues with the your php version OR php modules, Please check your php modules (TTF) and install all modules which are install on your localhost.